# How to show 'name' column of table instead of id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables; Income, Expenses and IncomeExpenses. IncomeExpenses contains foreign keys of both Income and Expenses.

```
class IncomeExpenses extends Model
{
    public function income(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Income::class);
    }
    public function expense(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Expenses::class);
    }
}
```

Also, IncomeId and ExpensesId are used in view and I use dropdownlists for them and what I want to achieve is that after I add new record with those dropdownlists I want to show title of IncomeId or ExpensesId instead of id. Yes I know it is better to use eager loading but I do not know how to achieve it.
Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $incexp = IncomeExpenses::find($id);
        $income=IncomeExpenses::with('income')->get();
        return view('incomeExpense.show', compact('incexp','income'));
    }
```

Income model:

```
class Income extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Expenses model

```
 class Expenses extends Model
    {
        //
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="card bg-muted">
    <h1>{{$incexp->IncomeExpense}}</h1>
    <small>Added at {{$incexp->created_at}}</small>
    <small> Type of Income:{{$income->income->title}}</small>
    <small> Money:{{$incexp->SumOfMoney}}</small>
    <small> Comments:{{$incexp->Comments}}</small>
    <small> Type of Expenses:{{$incexp->ExpenseId}}</small>

    </div>
```

Comment: which row is shows id? this => {{$incexp->IncomeExpense}}  or this => {{$incexp->ExpenseId}}

Comment: {{$incexp->ExpenseId}} and {{$incexp->IncomeId}} well in create view  there are dropdowns for ExpenseId and IncomeId and I properly gets name to be shown but after I add new record in list view ExpenseId and IncomeId are shown as id and not as title

Comment: @AliÖzen, I hope you get my point if not let me know :)

Comment: They way you are showing id you can do the same for showing name.

Comment: @HidayatUllah, Yes I have tried now I have an error of "Call to undefined relationship [income] on model [App\Income]." Please Hidayat help. I have edited my question now I use belognsTo instead of haveOne

Comment: Define Relationship in the other two model as well.